# How to create a macro that types out inputs as a human would, as opposed to pasting? (Or software recommendation - Windows 7)

Tags: automation, macros

I am looking for a method of macro creation that allows for text to be typed as a human would, key by key, as opposed to pasting blocks of text all at once.

I'm open to just about any option that can achieve this, including software options. I've been looking for a day and found nothing that doesn't require that I manually program them out key-by-key.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these options have a record macro feature so you type out the text once then map that macro to a (set) of keys.

1. If you are doing a lot of coding then I would suggest **Netbeans**. It is great for adding code blocks, or simple settups. I have had

   ```
   System.out.println();
   ```

   mapped to Ctrl + Alt + p for a long time and it has come in really handy while programming Java.
2. If you have a lot of different files to work with and need an editor that can handle almost all languages than the other option I would recommend it **Notepad++**. It can handle almost any language that you may need to work on and has many other features that help out.